# How to make sales badges in Algolia instantsearch results for Magento 1

Tags: php, magento, algolia

I'm trying to make sales badges to hits in Algolia instantsearch results for Magento v1, but I can't figure out how.

Could someone please point me in the right direction :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update the instant search page. [Transform records' data](https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/frontend-events/#instant-search-page-events) ([InstantSearch.js `hits` doc](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits)) to see if you should display the badge.

And then you'll need to [override the template](https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/customize-instantsearch/) to actually display it.